# Comparing two PST DateTime objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to convert a given date to **PST timezone** and compare it with a given date time. I am getting the current time in PST using the following method:

```
var today = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
})
```

The output is of the following format:

```
3/16/2022, 12:27:28 AM
```

Now, I am creating a date time object to compare with the above date time:

```
var cmpdate = new Date("2022-03-16 23:59:59").toLocaleString("en-US")
```

Output is the following:

```
3/16/2022, 11:59:59 PM
```

I wanted the comparing date time object to be the last moment of the given date. That's why passing `23:59:59`.

Now, when I compare these two, I am not getting the output properly because `toLocaleString()` is converting the dates to string and the comparison is happening as string comparison.

```
 if(today <= cmpdate)
    console.log("yes")
 else
    console.log("no")
```

For the given above input, it is printing `no` always but ideally it should be printing `yes`. The issue is because of the `12:27:28` present in first time object, I guess. Then I don't know how to resolve this without using any third party libraries.

Any hints on how to implement this PST comparison?

Comment: You already know the problem. *"`toLocaleString()` is converting the dates to string"*. Just don't convert them to a string?!

Comment: @deceze Then please enlighten me on how to convert to PST timezone for comparison without using `toLocaleString()`!

Comment: It rather seems to me that you need to ensure `Date` understands that your set March 16th date is supposed to be in PST time, then compare that to "now": `new Date <= new Date("2022-03-16T23:59:59-08:00")`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a dedicated library for this purpose, [`luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) for example will make this very straightforward.

We can use the [`.fromFormat()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromformat) function to parse the cmpdate value, while setting the correct `zone`.

Getting current time just means a call to [`DateTime.now()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimenow), then calling [`.setZone()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimesetzone).

Once we have created our values, we can simply use the <, >, <=, and >= operators to compare them. See [`comparing-datetimes`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/math?id=comparing-datetimes).

Rather then setting the cmpdate value to 2022-03-16 23:59:59 and using `<=`, I'd suggest setting it to 2022-03-17 00:00:00 and using the `<` operator. This simplifies the logic:

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;
const zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';

let cmpdate = DateTime.fromFormat('2022-03-17 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', { zone });
let today = DateTime.now().setZone(zone);

console.log(`cmpdate (${zone}): `, cmpdate.toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
console.log(`today (${zone}):   `, today.toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));

console.log('today < cmpdate:               ', today < cmpdate);


// Skipping the conversion of now() to LA time will also work, since the timestamps are converted to epoch timestamps before comparing
console.log('now() < cmpdate:               ', DateTime.now() < cmpdate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.3.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-Nw0Abk+Ywwk5FzYTxtB70/xJRiCI0S2ORbXI3VBlFpKJ44LM6cW2WxIIolyKEOxOuMI90GIfXdlZRJepu7cczA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

You *can* do this with native JS Date values, by getting the time in the relevant timezone, as an ISO string, then comparing.

By passing the locale 'sv' to the .toLocaleString() call, we convert the date to an ISO string.

Since ISO date strings are sortable, we can compare using the < > etc operators.

```js
const timeZone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
const now = new Date();

const cmpdate = '2022-03-17 00:00:00';

let today = now.toLocaleString('sv', { timeZone });
let tomorrow = new Date(now.getTime());
tomorrow.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
tomorrow = tomorrow.toLocaleString('sv', { timeZone });

console.log('cmpdate (LA Time): ', cmpdate);
console.log('today (LA Time):   ', today);
console.log('tomorrow (LA Time):', tomorrow);

console.log('today < cmpdate:   ', today < cmpdate);
console.log('tomorrow < cmpdate:', tomorrow < cmpdate);
```